# for loop through stdin using previous item

Tags: python, bash, stdin, sys

I would like to compare a line to the previous one without storing anything in memory (no dictionaries).

Sample data:

```
a   2
file    1
file    2
file    4
for 1
has 1
is  2
lines   1
small   1
small   2
test    1
test    2
this    1
this    2
two 1
```

Pseudocode:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    word, count = line.split()
    if word == previous_word:
        print(word, count1+count2)
```

I know I would use `enumerate` or `dict.iteritems` over an array but I can't on `sys.stdin`.

Desired output:

```
a   2
file    7
for 1
has 1
is  2
lines   1
small   3
test    3
this    3
two 1
```

Comment: Can there be more than 2 repetitions?

Comment: You need to assign `previous_word` to something

Comment: Hi, I edited my question, so I am looking for something that might work for more than 2 repititions but they will be next to one another. I know previous_word and count1, count2 aren't assigned; I'm not sure if I can make this approach work though?

Comment: So it's *Python* or *bash*? Btw, you **can** use *enumerate* on `sys.stdin`.

Comment: "I'm not sure if I can make this approach work though"  -  So, give it a try -- turn your pseudocode into code -- and then post your code, actual output, and debugging you have attempted;  that will form the basis of a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which is what makes a good question on SO

Comment: What do you mean by "without storing anything in memory"?  If you write code like `for line in sys.stdin` then a line will be read from stdin and stored in memory in the variable `line`.  Perhaps you mean `without storing *everything* in memory`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic logic is to keep track of the previous word.  If the current word matches, accumulate the count.  If not, print the previous word and its count, and start over.  There's a little special code to handle the first and last iterations.

```
stdin_data = [
    "a   2",
    "file    1",
    "file    2",
    "file    4",
    "for 1",
    "has 1",
    "is  2",
    "lines   1",
    "small   1",
    "small   2",
    "test    1",
    "test    2",
    "this    1",
    "this    2",
    "two 1",
]  

previous_word = ""
word_ct = 0

for line in stdin_data:
    word, count = line.split()
    if word == previous_word:
        word_ct += int(count)
    else:
        if previous_word != "":
            print(previous_word, word_ct)
        previous_word = word
        word_ct = int(count)

# Print the final word and count
print(previous_word, word_ct)
```

Output:

```
a 2
file 7
for 1
has 1
is 2
lines 1
small 3
test 3
this 3
two 1
```

Comment: I believe that I technically beat you to it by 6 sec. +1 to you!

Comment: @MadPhysicist: When I posted, the refresh didn't show your answer.  Network lag.  :-)  Yes, +1 to you!

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to compare a line to the previous one without storing anything in memory (no dictionaries).

To be able to sum up counts from all previous lines with similar word, you need to maintain some state.

Usually this job is suited to `awk`. You may consider this command:

```
awk '{a[$1] += $2} p && p != $1{print p, a[p]; delete a[p]} {p = $1} 
END { print p, a[p] }' file
```

```
a 2
file 7
for 1
has 1
is 2
lines 1
small 3
test 3
this 3
two 1
```

Using `delete`, this solution is not storing whole file in memory. State is maintained only for the duration while processing lines with same first word.

**Awk References:**

- [Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)
- [Awk Tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

Comment: thank you? what is awk/where can I find out more about it

Comment: I have added couple of `awk` references in my answer

Answer (score 2):

Your code is almost there. While it is commendable not to want to store the whole thing in memory, you will have to store the cumulative components of the previous line:

```
prev_word, prev_count = '', 0
for line in sys.stdin:
    word, count = line.split()
    count = int(count)
    if word == prev_word:
        prev_count += count
    elif prev_count:
        print(prev_word, prev_count)
        prev_word, prev_count = word, count
```